# compute a column in a dataframe by comparison of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compute a column in a dataframe and using this code-

```
df[col3] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] == x[col2], axis=1)
```

It is working fine apart from cells where there is no entry. If the corresponding cells in both the columns are empty, I want it to return `True` but it is returning `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest is compare columns with repalce missing values to same scalars like `nan string` in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].fillna('nan string') == df['col2'].fillna('nan string')
```

Comment: Interesting technique, and a very helpful one. works for me. thanks